# i18next multilanguage site with URL change

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess, i18next

I am trying to add multiple language support to a web-site, that doesn't have .php files and I am doing it with [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/).
But URLs now need to be like www.mysite/en/about/. I decided to make something like that

```
 window.history.pushState("", "", '/en' + window.location.pathname);
```

And then on changing the language:

```
 $('.lang').on("change", function() {
    window.history.pushState("", "", '/' + $(this).val() + window.location.pathname.substring(3));
    i18next.changeLanguage($(this).val(), function() {
       $('.page_text').localize();
       $('.info').localize();
    });
 });
```

The problem is when someone shares a link like www.mysite/fr/about/ it gets an error. I can redirect it to www.mysite/about/ via .htaccess, but how can I then get the language "/fr" parameter?

If you know any other ways around without using .htaccess, I'll be glad to hear them out.

Thank you for your help.

**Edit:**

The error is 404.
The routing is simply folders with .html files.

Comment: What error is it getting?

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you are doing page routing? Are you just providing static html from a backend server based on the url? Or are you using a framework to render conditionally on the url once they receive the whole app/site.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html using mod_rewrite should enable you to rewrite the urls containing the language to urls not having them

Comment: @jamuhl yes, I am currently doing this, but as I have mentioned, my problem is that I can't get the language part of url (www.mysite/fr/about/) after I rewrite it